# HTML table icons not sitting in a line

Tags: html, css

I have a tick based pricing table. Two of the ticks are not in vertical alignment with the other ticks.

For your convinence I've taken a print screen and highlited them:

[image: Screenshot]

The page itself is found [here](https://www.workbooks.com/location-aware).

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML, and css, in your question, don't pretend your URLs are code, they are not. By all means link to external demos or, if it's a front-end question, CSS, HTML and/or JavaScript, use the inline code-editor available above the textarea in which you wrote your question. Help us to help you, we shouldn't have to follow links around the internet in order to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment David, unfortunately I can't post links yet due to my new account status. As the table is extensive posting that as html code will create an extremely long question length. So posting as code seems my best option.

Comment: Then you need to reduce the size of your code to the minimum ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) amount necessary to reproduce your problem. Add the code, and then I suspect you'll be able to add the relevant links (albeit perhaps not all of them). You can either leave your links as 'code' (and I'm sure someone will edit them to be real links), or you could use the [Stack Snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) tool, to put runnable (front-end) code in your question, so you won't need to link anywhere.

Comment: Thanks again, I've not seen the Stack Snippet tool before. Will go and do my research before posting again.

Comment: Did my research, Stack Snippet is awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this to avoid changing the style sheets. Although please do keep in mind that stylesheets are a better method to achieve this.

`<td style="text-align: center !important; width: 145px !important;">`

Comment: Thanks for this, although will try to gain access to the CSS in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is wheb you include a text "Restricted" inside `td` rather than the image with the green tick. You should set the width of `td` lower so that the green ticks are aligned

Just change this css

```
table.header-features tr td {
   text-align: center !important;
   width: 212px !important;
}
```

to this:

```
table.header-features tr td {
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 145px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need a solution without changing the style-sheets. Is there one available?

Comment: @Sam No there is not a solution that doesn't include style-sheets changing. You cann't just change HTML markup and achieve the result you want. You must change the CSS

Answer (score 1):

The 'width' property in table elements is not always respected by browsers and can lead to inconsistent behavior. Instead, use properties like 'min-width' and 'max-width' when trying to set table widths.

Ex.

```
table.header-features tr td {
   text-align: center !important;
   min-width: 33% !important;
   max-width: 33% !important;
}
```